# How to receive Meteor collection callbacks only after initial result set is loaded

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm observing a collection in Meteor and it works fine, however I'd like to weed out callbacks that occur during the initial rendering of the page and only act on events that occur after the page has been rendered to the user once. How can I do this in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, don't do what I'm trying to do but rather store the date that the template was rendered and only process collection events that occur after that date.